# sql query Polygon of Points in MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlgeometry

Below query successfully executes in MySQL but throwing an error in MSSQL as equivalent functions may not exist.

Can anybody provide me an example to equivalent query in MSSQL 2012 ?

```
CREATE TABLE geo_tmp
( startIp  varchar(12)    NOT NULL,
   endIp    varchar(12)    NOT NULL);    

INSERT INTO geo_tmp VALUES(16777216,16777471);   
INSERT INTO geo_tmp VALUES(16777472,16778239);   
INSERT INTO geo_tmp VALUES(16778240,16778271);   

select startIp,endIp, 
POLYGON(LINESTRING( POINT(startIp, -1), POINT(endIp,   -1), POINT(endIp,    1), POINT(startIp,  1), POINT(startIp, -1)))  
from geo_tmp
```

Can we please get equivalent polygon query converted to MSSQL.

for MSSQL to find the POINT; `select Geometry::Point(startIp, -1, 4326) from geo_tmp works`., but it is not equivalent to polygon query written above in mysql.